# Packet loss during 3way handshake

Tags: c++, sockets, tcp, winsock, handshake

I need to perform a 3way stop and wait handshake between client and server applications written in c++ (with winsock 2) for an assignment. The client sends a SYN. The server increments the client sequence number and sends a SYN-ACK. The client increments the server sequence number and sends an ACK.

To simulate packet loss, the client and server are connected to an intermediary Router program that occasionally does not forward packets, causing loss. How should I structure my sendto(), select(), recvfrom() statements to account for possible packet loss?

For example, if the SYN is lost and client times out, resend it. If the SYN-ACK is lost, client times out and resends SYN. I have no idea what to do if the ACK is lost though.

**Edit:** It basically goes like this on my client:

- Send SYN.
- Loop while select() statement fails and resend SYN
- Receive SYN-ACK
- Send ACK
- Loop to possibly re-receive SYN-ACK if ACK was lost.

How do I know when to stop looping?

Comment: Seems like this previously asked question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460640/doubt-in-three-way-handshake-in-tcp-and-unix-listen-function

Comment: I understand that the SYN-ACK will be resent and then the ACK will be resent, but how do I check for it with select()? I have to loop recvfrom() and check that it is the same SYN-ACK?

Comment: In TCP, you don't have any control over the SYNs and ACKs. The only thing you can do is put the socket into non-blocking mode so `connect()` works asynchronously and then use the timeout feature of `select()` to wait for the connection to be established. If `select()` times out, close the socket and start over.

Comment: This is my own implementation of TCP through UDP. Sockets are of type SOCK_DGRAM.

Comment: There is no reply to the final ACK.  Once the client sends that ACK, it has to consider the connection established on its end.  Whether or not the server receives the ACK doesn't matter to the client.  If the server never receives the ACK, the connection won't be established on its end. Eventually socket activity on the client side will fail with errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` can be used to check when a socket can be read from without blocking.

As for checking which sent packet the ACK belongs to, you check the sequence number.

If you don't receive an ACK within the timeout, you simple re-send the last packet. It doesn't matter what kind of packet you sent, if you don't receive an ACK you should resend it.